# Azure Redirect HTTPS returns 404

Tags: azure, iis, https, web-config

So I wrote the following Rewrite rule in Azure web.config to redirect traffic to https:

```
   <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
   </rule>
```

And it works fine on the production site (custom domain).

However, on our dev instance (azurewebsites.net address), I am getting the following when trying to access http or https
[image: HTTP]
[image: HTTPS]

I'm not sure what the issue is at the moment

Comment: silly question...is your dev/test on a shared environment? pretty sure ssl is not supported on free or shared

Comment: Valid question, and no it's on a dedicated enviro. If I take the rewrite out of the web config, I can access http and https individually, but when the rewrite is in place, the above happens

Comment: silly question number 2. do you have the nodes that come before your  rule name? <configuration><system.webServer><rewrite><rules>.. I just did a test on a Basic website that I have running with your rules and it worked. When I access HTTP I get redirected to HTTPS